# How to combine this SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, phpmyadmin

i have this query that it works ok but doesn't retrieve exact information (firstname,lastname), it only gives second name

```
SELECT b.email, c.value AS firstname, a.updated_at, d.added_at
    FROM  `wishlist` AS a
    INNER JOIN customer_entity AS b 
ON a.customer_id = b.entity_id
    INNER JOIN customer_entity_varchar AS c 
ON a.customer_id = c.entity_id
    AND c.attribute_id = ( 
    SELECT attribute_id
    FROM eav_attribute
    WHERE attribute_code =  'lastname'
    AND entity_type_id = b.entity_type_id ) 
    INNER JOIN wishlist_item AS d 
ON a.wishlist_id = d.wishlist_id
    INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity AS e 
ON d.product_id = e.entity_id
    LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order AS f ON 
f.customer_email = b.email
    LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_item AS g 
ON ( f.entity_id = g.order_id
    AND g.sku LIKE CONCAT( e.sku,  '%' ) 
    AND g.product_type =  'simple' ) 
    WHERE d.added_at
    BETWEEN  '2015-01-01'
    AND  '2015-02-01'
    GROUP BY b.email
```

This query if i execute will result all customers fullname correctly

```
SELECT entity_id, group_concat(VALUE SEPARATOR ' ') AS fullname 
FROM customer_address_entity_varchar AS val
INNER JOIN eav_attribute AS attr 
      ON attr.attribute_id  = val.attribute_id
WHERE attr.attribute_code IN ( 'firstname',  'lastname' )
```

How can i edit the 1st query part of retrieving the customer name as the example on the 2nd query?
I am a little bit confused , i tried many combination in sql but non of them will work.

**EDIT:** i have updated the 1st long query, price should not be there. Also i understand that the group makes no sense but i need only 1 row per customer so i will have to hide the products. If possible all the products to be like `wishproduct_1,wishproduct2,wishproduct3 ..` in the same row be awesome.

Comment: This is why you never use EAV tables for things like first and last name that you will want to frequenlty query.  But in general you would join to the table once for each field you want.

Comment: So is there a workaround?

Comment: Incidentally, while mysql will accept this kind of grouping, it does not give consistent results and you should use group by the sme way every other major database does instead of grouping on only one field. Your group by is definitely a SQL antipattern.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT b.email,
       h.price as firstname,
       c.price AS lastname, 
       a.updated_at, 
       d.added_at
FROM  `wishlist` AS a
INNER JOIN customer_entity AS b 
      ON a.customer_id = b.entity_id
INNER JOIN customer_entity_varchar AS c 
      ON a.customer_id = c.entity_id
      AND c.attribute_id = 
      ( 
          SELECT attribute_id
          FROM eav_attribute
          WHERE attribute_code =  'lastname'
          AND entity_type_id = b.entity_type_id 
       ) 
 INNER JOIN customer_entity_varchar AS h 
      ON a.customer_id = c.entity_id
      AND c.attribute_id = 
      ( 
          SELECT attribute_id
          FROM eav_attribute
          WHERE attribute_code =  'firstname'
          AND entity_type_id = b.entity_type_id 
       )       
INNER JOIN wishlist_item AS d 
      ON a.wishlist_id = d.wishlist_id
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity AS e 
      ON d.product_id = e.entity_id
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order AS f 
     ON f.customer_email = b.email
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_item AS g 
     ON ( f.entity_id = g.order_id
     AND g.sku LIKE CONCAT( e.sku,  '%' ) 
     AND g.product_type =  'simple' ) 
WHERE d.added_at
    BETWEEN  '2015-01-01' AND  '2015-02-01'
GROUP BY b.email, h.price,  c.price,  a.updated_at,  d.added_at
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I assumed that the field containing the actual first name would be the same as the one containing the last name (although price seems to be an odd choice).  Also since I used correct grouping, you may notice that you will get more records. In that case one or more of teh fields in the group by need to be changed to an aggregate function such as Max() or Min() in order to have one record per email. Your business rules would need to dictate which aggregate function you would apply though.

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply,helps a lot to understand things.I was executing all night long yesterday sql queries and i am also trying to read more stuff. Brings joy once you success :) About the field price you are right it shouldn't be there (i have updated 1st long query)The group i understand is wrong but i will have to hide the products as there will be huge amount of rows(possible to add same customer's wishlist products in same column?(of course remove sku and product_id columns in this case. About your query it gives error but i will try to use it as a source of test!price=wrong

Comment: HLGEM In your query there is a typo error in the 2nd line `h.price as firstname` should have a comma, good that i catch, please Edit!Now the query execute correct (if i replace price in `SELECT`` with value or something else) but doesn't give any records!Sure i will play around but it is very very strange, seems like my 1st query but no records. Tried remove things from group or select but still no goal. In the middle with Joins etc i do not understand a lot, sorry.